# Java: insert a date within a Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to connect java with mysql but I'm having the next problem with an insert query, the values of a date keeps subtracting themselves for example if I put the date 1995-04-16 it will try to input the value 1975 in the database.

The code I'm using is the next:

```
public void insertIntoUsuario() {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        System.out.println("Ingrese su cedula: ");
        int cedula = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese sus nombres: ");
        String nombres = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese sus apellidos: ");
        String apellidos = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento: ");
        String date = scan.next();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(date).getTime());

        System.out.println("Ingrese su ingreso mensual: ");
        float ingresos_mensuales = scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre de usuario: ");
        String nombre_usuario = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Ingrese una pass virtual: ");
        String pass_virtual = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Admin: por defecto es 0");
        int is_admin = 0;
        System.out.println("Visita: ");
        int first_visit = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println(sqlDate + "f");

        st.executeUpdate("insert into usuario (cedula, nombres, apellidos, fecha_nacimiento, ingresos_mensuales, nombre_usuario, pass_virtual, is_admin, first_visit) VALUES ('"
                + cedula
                + "','"
                + nombres
                + "','"
                + apellidos
                + "',"
                + sqlDate
                + ",'"
                + ingresos_mensuales
                + "','"
                + nombre_usuario
                + "','"
                + pass_virtual
                + "','"
                + is_admin
                + "','" + first_visit + "') ");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: use preparedstatement.

Comment: `+ sqlDate + ` is the same as saying `+ sqlDate.toString() + ` ... this is not what you want, see previous comment for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appending sqlDate in String will create it as String and this is the problem.

There are two possible solution

1. You can use Prepared Statement

or

2. If you want to Stick to Statement just leave your date in String and parse it in query like
   following

   st.executeUpdate("insert into usuario (cedula, nombres, apellidos, fecha_nacimiento, ingresos_mensuales, nombre_usuario, pass_virtual, is_admin, first_visit) VALUES ('"
                   + cedula
                   + "','"
                   + nombres
                   + "','"
                   + apellidos
                   **+ "', to_char("
                   + date
                   + ",'yyyy-mm-dd'),'"**
                   + ingresos_mensuales
                   + "','"
                   + nombre_usuario
                   + "','"
                   + pass_virtual
                   + "','"
                   + is_admin
                   + "','" + first_visit + "') ");

Comment: to_char needs to be used with an specific version of mysql or something? I tried this and it says that this function doesn't exist 
By the way thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use PreparedStatement like below:

```
public class DateExample
    { 
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            String source="1995-04-16";              
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");                       
            java.sql.Date d=(Date) format.parse(source);             
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");        
            Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee", "root", "root");   
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into table values(?)");   
            java.sql.Date d= new java.sql.Date(format.parse(source).getTime());       
            ps.setDate(1,d);    
            ps.executUpdate();
        }
    }
```